# Rails and Active Record: SQL Equivalent

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I'm trying to select just one column for many records in a table. This does not produce what I'm looking for. The SQL equivalent of what I'm trying to produce is:

```
SELECT OneColumn FROM Table WHERE ForeignKey = 1
```

I've tried many of the suggestions in the Rails Guide for Active Record, but none have worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from rails 3.2+ you have [#pluck](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/pluck) :

```
Table.where( ForeignKey: 1 ).pluck( :OneColumn )
```

if you have troubles due to non-conventionnal column or table names, try :

```
Table.where( Table.arel_table["ForeignKey"].eq 1 ).pluck( Table.arel_table["OneColumn"])
```

If you just want "low-level" SQL queries, try [#select_all](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/DatabaseStatements/select_all) or [#select_values](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.8/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/DatabaseStatements/select_values)

Answer (score 0):

Use [`pluck`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/pluck):

```
Table.where(ForeignKey: 1).pluck(:OneColumn)
```